# onclick slide to page down not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this website

www.homepreneurawards.com

when navbar menu is clicked it wont slide to the specific div content what could be the issue

```
 <header class="header type-1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo-block">
                <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="http://homepreneurawards.com/Homepreneur/img/logo.gif" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <nav class="main-nav">
                <ul class="anchor-navigation">
                    <li><a class="anchor-scroll" href="#aboutbrandavatar">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a class="anchor-scroll" href="#whoishomepreneur">HOMEPRENEUR ?</a></li>
                    <li><a class="anchor-scroll" href="#categories">CATEGORIES</a></li>
                    <li><a class="anchor-scroll" href="#jurymembers">JURY MEMBERS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="anchor-scroll" href="#timeline">PROCESS FLOW</a></li>
                    <li><a class="anchor-scroll" href="#organizers">ORGANIZERS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="anchor-scroll" href="#sponsorspartners">SPONSORS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="anchor-scroll" href="#partnerscontent">PARTNERS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="anchor-scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <button class="cmn-toggle-switch"><span></span></button>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: I would be more concerned of the page loading time. With 6.9mb site you won't even have visitors to navigate through your site.

Comment: Maybe this is not a solution to your problem, but you are loading jQuery several times in your page. Which impacts the loading of your page
`3.2.1 / jquery.min.js`,`jquery-3.2.1.js`, `jquery-2.1.4.min.js`
Try using it once before loading before all the other plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your function in anchors.navigation.js

```
function setImmediateAnchor(anchorObject, time) {
    scrollFlag = 1;
    if (currentAnchor) {  -- THIS LINE
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': contentTop[anchorObject.attr('href')].top
        }, time, function() {
            $(scrollLinkSelector).parent().removeClass('active');
            anchorObject.parent().addClass('active');
            window.location.hash = '#/' + anchorObject.attr('href').substr(1);
            currentAnchor = anchorObject.attr('href');
            scrollFlag = 0;
        });
    }
}
```

The condition if (currentAnchor) is failing because currentAnchor is empty. You have set it to  currentAnchor = window.location.hash.replace('/', '') which will be empty when your page is loaded because you does not have anything in url after http://www.homepreneurawards.com

There are 2 solution for it which ever you find feasible.

1. Add a condition below your initialization code to check if currentAnchor is empty then set it to some value say "#initialized" like below.

   ```
       var contentTop = {},
       contentOffset = 87,
       currentAnchor = window.location.hash.replace('/', ''),
       scrollFlag = 0,
       scrollLinkSelector = '.anchor-scroll';

       -- add this condition.
       if(currentAnchor =='')
       {
        currentAnchor = '#initialized';
       }
   ```
2. You can simply check for empty values in you function setImmediateAnchor like below notice 3rd line and handle empty values.

   ```
      function setImmediateAnchor(anchorObject, time) {
       scrollFlag = 1;
       if (currentAnchor == '' || currentAnchor) {  -- THIS LINE
           $('html,body').stop().animate({
               'scrollTop': contentTop[anchorObject.attr('href')].top
           }, time, function() {
               $(scrollLinkSelector).parent().removeClass('active');
               anchorObject.parent().addClass('active');
               window.location.hash = '#/' + anchorObject.attr('href').substr(1);
               currentAnchor = anchorObject.attr('href');
               scrollFlag = 0;
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Or you can use any other feasible way, the core problem lies in that condition that does not allow you to scroll since your variable is empty. You can fix either way which you find feasible.

Answer (score 0):

presuming it is all on one page,

```
<li><a class="anchor-scroll" href="#aboutbrandavatar">ABOUT</a></li>

<div id="#aboutbrandavatar">
  scrolls to here once navbar is clicked
</div>
```

you can also try

```
<a href="#" name="aboutbrandavatar">

<div id="aboutbrandavatar">
  My div
</div>
```

Comment: www.homepreneurawards.com see this site and click on the navbar

Comment: can you try to take out the class="anchor-scroll"

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you may be preventing the default click action of the link? If you manually go to the link URL e.g. http://www.homepreneurawards.com/#/aboutbrandavatar you will see that the scroll works as expected and further clicks work without an issue.

The URL structure does not look the same as a standard anchor link either and this could be causing you some issues?
Instead of /#/aboutbrandavatar I would expect to see #aboutbrandavatar